# Add new library

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, onsen-ui

I'm trying to figure out the right way to add any eventual new library (for example I need angularJS ui-router) in an onsen app.

I installed bower and then downloaded ui-router.
Since I do not know exactly the way Gulp is used, I got confused on what I'm suppose to do.

At the moment, I have the following folders:
**bower_components**, hooks, merges, node, modules, platforms, plugins, **www**

The index.html has the following reference:

What I suppose to do, now?

1. manually copy the ui-router js files in /www/lib/
2. configure gulp to copy the files automatically
3. change the script tag src and make the reference to the bower_component folder
4. change the Bower default folder

could you please guide me on sort it out?
tnx

Comment: You can use gulp to move the files into your www/lib folder. There are also some nice libs to integrate bower with gulp.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. 
At the end I chose the option 2.

I edited the file gulpfile.js  adding a new custom task supposed to copy the missing bower libraries.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I chose the option 2.

I edited the file gulpfile.js  adding a new custom task supposed to copy the missing bower libraries.

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('copy-bower-libs', function() {
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/www/lib/bower/js"))
});
```